# How to get values of mutiple checkbox value using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

in my html page:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content" ng-controller="InboxMailCtrl">
        <tr ng-repeat="CU in InboxList">
            <td class="check-mail">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="CU.Selected" value="{{CU.InboxMailID}}"   class="i-checks" > 
            </td>
            <td class="text-right mail-date">{{CU.time}}</td>
        </tr>
        <button  ng-click="Delete()"></button>
     </div>
 </body>
```

and in my js file :

```
var InboxMailCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {

    BindInboxList();
    function BindInboxList() {

        $http({
            url: "MailRoute/getDataForMailInbox",
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            data: obj,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            debugger;
            $scope.InboxList = response;

        }).error(function (error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    }


$scope.Delete = function () {
        debugger
        $scope.MailNameArray = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.InboxList, function (CU) {
            if (!!CU.selected) $scope.MailNameArray .push(CU.InboxMailID);
        })
    }
```

`$scope.Delete` gets selected ckeckbox items value in `MailNameArray` but I am not able to push selected checkbox data into this array.

What is wrong?

I am using webAPI controller and `getDataForMailInbox` is a function in api controller.

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle or somethin else, so we can see what actually happens and should happen....

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-model="CU.Selected"
             ^
```

and

```
if (!!CU.selected)
         ^
```

are different

Comment: now i have edit the full html code here.i have changed the (!!cu.selected) to CU.selected but not working

Comment: er.. you need to fix the uppercase S in `ng-model`

Comment: thanks a lot.100 % right solutions.can you tell me how to send the MailNameArray  array into webapi controller please?

Comment: just pass the array into `$http` options `data` will do

Comment: can you modify my delete function please??.actually i am new in angularjs.

Comment: that is out of scope of this question. You can attempt it yourself first, if can't solve, submit a new question with your code.